# Custom content of Fullcalendar event after eventResize

Tags: fullcalendar

I try to set dynamically the content of a FullCalendar event after the user would have resized it but I can't figure out how to achieve this, since both `eventResize` and `eventResizeStop` don't get the element in their callback.

I have also tried to modify the event in `eventResizeStop` and to get the value in `eventRender` (since I noticed that a rerender is called after resize stop) but this ain't work because still get the "old" event content.

Any idea how to achieve this?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     eventRender: function (event, element) {
        console.log(event.something); // still same value
     },
     eventResizeStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
         event.something = 'try to push a new value'; // no effect
         $(this).find('.fc-title').replaceWith('something'); // no effect
     },
     eventResize: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
         $(this).find('.fc-title').replaceWith('something'); // no effect
     }
});
```

Mockup of what I would like to achieve:

before user modification:

```
-----------------
| event content |
-------v---------
```

after user modification of the length/duration of the event:

```
-----------------
| event content |
| is now not the|
| same anymore  |
-------v---------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution. Modifying the event in `eventResize` is effectively the right way but after doing so, the event should be updated in the calendar respectively an update should be explicitly called

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        console.log(event.something); 
    },
    eventResize: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
       event.something = 'my new value';
       $("#calendar").fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
   }
});
```